Network setup of 2 routers with 1 provided by ISP and 2 bought by me to host openVPN
I have ISP provided router GX Titanium-2122A (IP: 192.168.1.1), where I was able to port forward 1594 for UDP. I bought another TP link Archer C1200 router with OpenVPN server capabilities. I started the OpenVPN server on 1594 UDP port, generate certificate and export configs for openVPN client.
But I am not able to connect to OpenVPN client. I am missing major configs, like where do I provide my ISP router's WAN address (or public IP address). Also, once this is done I will need to configure DDNS server too, I am trying with some free options to start like no-IP with Let's encrypt cert, will go for paid one if this setup is working.
I have NAS and few other servers on this VPN server, wanted to expose for remote access.
Any help or documentation is deeply appreciated.
Exported configs
client
dev tun
proto udp
float
nobind
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo adaptive
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun
remote WAN_IP 1594
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>


What config do you have?

Added the exported configs in the question itself, if that helps.

Right – I see the exported config already has remote WAN_IP 1594 though. Is that what you were asking for?

Not exactly this is the setup that I did.
I checked on few other forums and figured that my IP is showing as different on different what's my IP sites, and that might be the issue.
I am not 100% sure how this will cause the issue. I pick my IP from what Google provides when I search what's my IP
Also, any idea how I can resolve this situation.

In that case... do you even have a public IP address dedicated to you? Does any of those reported addresses exactly match what your ISP router says its "WAN address" is?

This is also something I was not able to find.
My ISP provided router is GX Titanium-2122A and I have still not been able to find the WAN address on it. There is just no mention of it, I went to each and every page.
